# Serial Port Stream / Bash or C Script

Tags: linux, c, serial-port

I have a serial device (speed radar) that outputs data every 250ms.

Here is the info I have on the device:

```
1. Speed Packet Protocol
The Radar message packet consists of 7 bytes @ 1200 baud, no parity, 8 data bits, 1 start
bit. Messages are paced at 250mS intervals and are sent whether there is a target or not.
Char Description
1 <STX> Start of message
2 Status Radar status, as defined below
3 Patrol Speeds in binary from 4 to 255, Speed values below 4 are treated as
zero.
4 Target
5 Lock
6 Alt Alternate speed, as defined below
7 <ETX> End of message
1.1. Radar status byte
Bit Description/function if set
0 Low voltage error
1 Radio frequency interference error
2 Front antenna
3 Rear antenna
4 Moving mode
5 Alternate mode (fastest or slow)
6 Opposite direction mode
7 Always set (Indicated a speed packet)
Neither antenna being selected indicates standby.
Both antennae selected indicates a self-test is in progress. Test results are not sent, the
radar either returns to normal operation if successful or ceases communication in the
event of failure.
1.2. Alternate Speed
If the alternate mode bit is set, the alternate speed should be displayed. This will be
fastest if in opposite direction or slow if in same direction.
1.3. Message Receipt
Each message received should be time stamped and removed after 1 second if it has not
been replaced by a new message. The only exception is the self-test message, which
allows 8 seconds for the test to complete.
1.4. Example
Received sequence 02, 244(0xf4), 50, 99, 75, 01, 03.
Front antenna, moving mode, fastest mode, opposite direction mode, patrol speed of 50,
strongest target at 99, a locked speed of 75 and a no fastest target (since the value is
less that 4).
```

Using:

```
minicom -b 1200 -D /dev/ttyUSB0 -8 -H -w
```

The data looks like this if reading 0:

```
02 c8 00 00 00 00 03
```

And this if its reading something else:

```
02 c8 00 16 00 00 03
```

or

```
02 c8 00 0f 00 00 03
```

So it would probably be like:

```
//How do I pipe the stream into the script??
"Get String Code Here"
//example string
$string=02 c8 00 16 00 00 03
//remove first part
$prefix=02 c8 00
//remove last part 
$suffix=00 00 03
//result which appears to be a hex value
$result=16 (22MPH)
//convert $result to decimal

echo $result to monitor/file/database
```

I've also come across a C script that I hope will work better:

```
    #include <stdio.h> /* Standard input/output definitions */
    #include <string.h> /* String function definitions */
    #include <unistd.h> /* UNIX standard function definitions */
    #include <fcntl.h> /* File control definitions */
    #include <errno.h> /* Error number definitions */
    #include <termios.h> /* POSIX terminal control definitions */



//Initialize serial port
int initport(int fd)
{
    int portstatus = 0;

    struct termios options;
    // Get the current options for the port...
    tcgetattr(fd, &options);
    // Set the baud rates to 115200...
    cfsetispeed(&options, B1200);
    cfsetospeed(&options, B1200);
    // Enable the receiver and set local mode...
    options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);

    options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    options.c_cflag |= CS8;
    //options.c_cflag |= SerialDataBitsInterp(8);           /* CS8 - Selects 8 data bits */
    options.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;                            // disable hardware flow control
    options.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);           // disable XON XOFF (for transmit and receive)
    //options.c_cflag |= CRTSCTS;                     /* enable hardware flow control */


    options.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;     //min carachters to be read
    options.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;    //Time to wait for data (tenths of seconds)


    // Set the new options for the port...
    //tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);


    //Set the new options for the port...
    tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
    if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options)==-1)
    {
        perror("On tcsetattr:");
        portstatus = -1;
    }
    else
        portstatus = 1;


    return portstatus;
}


/*
* 'open_port()' - Open serial port 1.
*
* Returns the file descriptor on success or -1 on error.
*/
int open_port(void)
{
    int fd; /* File descriptor for the port */
    fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDONLY | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);

    if (fd == -1)
    {
        /*
        * Could not open the port.
        */
        perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyUSB0 --- \n");
    }
    else
        fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);

    return (fd);
}

int main(void)
{

    int serial_fd = open_port();

    if(serial_fd == -1)
        printf("Error opening serial port /dev/ttyUSB0 \n");
    else
    {
        printf("Serial Port /dev/ttyUSB0 is now open \n");

        // READ PORT DATA 


        if(initport(serial_fd) == -1)
        {
            printf("Error Initializing port");
            close(serial_fd);
            return 0;
        }

        sleep(.5);
        //usleep(500000);
        //printf("size of data being sent = %ld", sizeof("~ver~\n\r"));

        sleep(.5);
        //usleep(500000);

        printf("\n\nNow closing Serial Port /dev/ttyUSB0 \n\n");

        close(serial_fd);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You've given lots of useful information, which is good. However, it's not entirely clear what you want to do. Clearly you want to process the data, but in what way? An example of input, and the required output, would help.

Comment: I'm just looking to filter the speed (strongest target) that will be overlaid on a CCTV system.  The higher numbers (like say over 30) would be tagged and sent to another script.  Example input "02 c8 00 32 00 00 03" expected output would be "32".

Comment: So it's just extracting the fourth byte? Do you need it converted to decimal?

Comment: I'm probably wrong in assuming that the output would be the speed in MPH.  If there's an way to do both just to make sure it's the actual number I'm looking for.

Comment: OK, I've included stuff to convert to decimal.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think all you need is:

```
"Get String Code Here"  
string="02 c8 00 16 00 00 03"  
result=$(echo ${string} | cut -w -f 3)
```

But that's in hexadecimal, so comparisons are going to be tricky:

```
decimalresult=$(printf "%d" 0x${result})
```

Of course, you can do this in one line, but I did it like that for clarity.

**Revised version**

You say you have a continuous stream and need to read it as part of the script. Shell scripts generally read in lines, so this is what we do:

- You use `minicom` and pipe its output into the script. Be sure to use the `-H` option to get hex output, since shell scripts don't play nicely with binary. Like this:
  `minicom -b 1200 -D /dev/ttyUSB0 -8 -H -w | this_script`
- The input is piped through `dd` to split it into chunks making up one message, adding a newline at the end.
- That goes into a loop that reads the seven items on each line, ignoring all except the fourth.
- The hex is converted to decimal and output.

  `dd conv=unblock cbs=21 |
  while read x x x hexresult x x x ; do
     decimalresult=$(printf "%d" 0x${hexresult})
     echo ${decimalresult}
  done`

I haven't tried it with a continuous stream, so you might have to tweak it a bit. In particular, you might need to add `obs=21` to the `dd` parameters (it might even be 20, not 21).

Comment: I should have clarified a little further.  I need a way to get the string into the script.  It's a constant stream with no EOF which is where I'm stuck.

Comment: It doesn't look like dd is fast enough.  I piped minicom into dd conv=unblock cbs=21, and it's sluggish.

Comment: Can you explain more? It will be a bit sluggish because of the rate the data is produced. Is a lot slower than without `dd`? Remember that `dd` will wait until it gets all 7 values before outputting them.

Comment: The output is choppy: http://i.imgur.com/txiPEMa.jpg  It puts out some errors: 4: printf: 0x: not completely converted  Realization:  It's probably coming through too fast.  There's probably a buffer of some sort that's filling up.  I'm thinking there needs to be a check of some sort to make sure that 02 is the start and 03 is the end.  If the string doesn't match, move along.  My preg match skills are terrible.

Comment: I was afraid a script might be too slow. I'd personally knock up a tiny C program to do this.

Comment: I'm not familiar at all with C.  I chose BASH as I know it a little.  I was thinking command line PHP as well.

Comment: I am not familiar with PHP!

Comment: I've edited the original post that includes the start of a C program.